# Get the number of records between 1 hour after and before mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

First of all, sorry for my english.

I try to put this on the easy way. I want to know how many records are between a certain time. This is the bussiness logic. We need to limit the number of bookings that a user can made in a specific time. An user can be book a service every 5 minutes but the number of admin users to setup the booking is limit to 3, in other words, only can be a 3 books in a range of 1 hour. For example:

```
11:20 AM
11:45 AM
11:55 AM
```

--

In this example users selected that time of booking. But if another or the same user wants to make a new booking only can be made after 12:20PM. I need a query that returns me the limit min and max of this records. Something like this:

```
TIME BOOK        MIN_TIME         MAX_TIME
11:20 AM         11:20AM          12:20AM
11:45 AM         11:20AM          12:20AM
11:55 AM         11:20AM          12:20AM
12:35PM          12:35PM          01:35PM
01:00PM          12:35PM          01:35PM
01:30PM          12:35PM          01:35PM
```

The range of min and max time is for every record that between in 1 hour.

Thanks for all your help.

EDIT:

This is what I have, but the results there are not that what I want:

```
SELECT b.id, b.time_book, hour_min, ADDTIME(hour_min, '01:00:00') AS hour_max 
FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT time_book, min(time_book) AS hour_min FROM bookings 
        WHERE book_date = "2017-07-14"
        GROUP BY time_book
        having hour_min between SUBTIME(time_book, '01:00:00') and time_book
) AS t
ON b.time_book= t.time_book
WHERE b.book_date = "2017-07-14"
ORDER BY b.time_book
```

this query returns this data for example:

```
id     pickup_time   hour_min   hour_max
10721  05:30:00      05:30:00   06:30:00
10366  06:45:00      06:45:00   07:45:00
10772  06:55:00      06:55:00   07:55:00
10769  08:10:00      08:10:00   09:10:00
10199  08:20:00      08:20:00   09:20:00
10182  08:45:00      08:45:00   09:45:00
10775  09:40:00      09:40:00   10:40:00
10776  09:40:00      09:40:00   10:40:00
10639  09:45:00      09:45:00   10:45:00
10649  10:00:00      10:00:00   11:00:00
```

Comment: `WHERE time_book BETWEEN time_book AND DATE_ADD(time_book, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations @Barmar. I type the query that I try to build. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the datatype of `time_book`? Things are much easier if you have a single `DATETIME` column, rather than separate date and time columns.

Comment: is time datatype. Yeah, it would by more easier but in this case we need this data in separate fields @Barmar

Comment: Then you should be using `ADDTIME` rather than `DATE_ADD`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, Got it. I'm going to make that chage. Could you help me with the query???

Comment: Do you have to deal with times periods that cross over midnight? That makes things even harder.

Comment: No, no sir. The last time of schedule booking is midnight @Barmar

Comment: It seems like the only use for this restriction is to prevent a user from booking _now_, not from fetching counts about times in the past.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @RickJames This restriction is to prevent users from scheduling more rides than allowed within 1 hour. For example, a user can schedule a ride at 11:05, another at 11:20 a second at 11:50, and so on. If someone else wants to schedule another ride must wait until drivers are available, which in this case are 3, so you can only program 3 rides, do not know if I do understand?

Comment: @RickJames It can't be made for drivers available, cause an user can make a schedule a ride in the future or can schedule a 1 or 2 or 3 rides in the same time

Comment: Ah - booking things in the future.  That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot hours trying to make this work, finally I could make it work. This is the query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.pickup_time, hour_min, addtime(hour_min, '01:00:00') AS hour_max
FROM bookingdetails b
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT b1.id,
       (
           SELECT MIN(t1.pickup_time)
           FROM bookingdetails t1 
           WHERE t1.pickup_date = '2017-07-14'
           AND t1.pickup_time BETWEEN b1.pickup_time - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE AND b1.pickup_time + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
        ) AS hour_min
        FROM bookingdetails b1
        WHERE b1.pickup_date = '2017-07-14'
    ) AS r
    ON b.id = r.id
ORDER BY b.pickup_time
```

Obviously It can be improve or better, but it works for me. Thanks for all help that I found in all site.